# How do I stop the timeout of sessions and make session time infinite? (PHP)

Tags: php, session, timeout, openid

I'm using OpenID (LightOpenID) with PHP and I can't help but notice that the session times out after a very short period of time, and it is a problem. How can I increase the session time to infinite? I've googled many methods but I don't believe I am adding the code in the correct places. If it's necessary for me to paste my code, just say so, but I didn't think it was needed. All help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Still not sure how to fix this..

Answer (score 1):

```
`

<?php 
       if(!isset($_SESSION["timeout"])){
         $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
       };
       $st = $_SESSION['timeout'] + 120; //session time is 2 minutes, Changing this value can help you.

      if(time() < $st){
        echo 'Session will last 2 minutes';
      }
  ?>`
```

Comment: where do I add this too though? The openID file, the authentication file, or you can just tell me what type of code to look for..?

Comment: With the help of your comment it seems that you are something in connection with social media, And the problem with you is that when request goes to a particular website (like google,or facebook) and when it comes back the session on your machine expires very soon.
Let me know if i am correct.
If i am correct then try use the above code when you authenticate the user, before starting the session.

Comment: Well, yes the session times out quicker than I want, but I am NOT using social media, I am using my own website with LightOpenID and PHP...